# Show the parametrized torus is a 2-dimensional smooth submanifold of$\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

How can I show that the parametrized torus $T=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : (\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}-a)^2 +z^2 =b^2 \}$ is a 2-dimensional smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ ? I was thinking of using the regular value theorem but I can't think of a smooth map that works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your function be $(\sqrt {x^2+y^2}-a)^2+z^2$, with $b^2$ the regular value.

Comment: But that isn't smooth?

Comment: The only places where it is not smooth is where $x=y=0$, which is not near your torus, so you're good.

Comment: OK thanks, do I need to restrict the domain then or can I just use $\mathbb{R}^3$ ?

Comment: Just us $R^3$, and show that the problem points are not close the torus points.

Comment: No, to apply the regular value theorem, you need a smooth function, so you do need to delete the $z$-axis from $\Bbb R^3$ before applying the theorem. *Then* you look to see that the function has no critical points on your level set. (This is a pedantic point, but you need to be careful.)

Comment: Can anyone explain how I can show that b^2 is a regular value?