# 2 dimensional Smooth manifold of $ℝ^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

From this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725459/show-the-parametrized-torus-is-a-2-dimensional-smooth-submanifold-of-mathbbr) ,

In attempt solve to this problem, I followed Yves Daoust's [approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358825/parametrisation-of-the-surface-a-torus) for parametise the torus as followed:

> A circle of radius $a$ centered at $(b,0)$ in the plane $xz$ has the
>   parametric equation
>
> $$x=a\cos(\theta)+b,z=a\sin(\theta),$$ with $\theta$ in the range
>   $[0,2\pi]$ for a full circle.
>
> Now you rotate the plane $xz$ around $z$ by $x\leftarrow
> > x\cos(\phi),y\leftarrow x\sin(\phi)$,  with $\phi$ in the range
>   $[0,2\pi]$ for a full turn,
>
> $$x=(a\cos(\theta)+b)\cos(\phi),\\ y=(a\cos(\theta)+b)\sin(\phi),\\
> z=a\sin(\theta).$$
>
> If you freeze $\theta$, you get a circle in a plane parallel to $xy$,
>   of the form:
>
> $$x=r\cos(\phi),y=r\sin(\phi).$$

I was trying to use [Preimage theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Preimage_Theorem) to prove the problem, however, I couldn't get far so when I went back to the original post and read Ted Shifrin's comment:

> to apply the regular value theorem, you need a smooth function, so you
>   do need to delete the z-axis from $ℝ^3$ before applying the theorem

I was wondering what does Ted mean by deleting the z-axis? I can't seem to grasp how it works. Much appreciated for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two comments: Once you have the parametrization, you could use *it* to prove that the torus is a $2$-dimensional manifold.

**EDIT**: The main idea is to check that the mapping $g\colon (0,2\pi)\times (0,2\pi)\to\Bbb R^3$ has rank $2$ everywhere. It follows that, restricting to its image (the torus), the inverse mapping gives a coordinate chart on most of the torus. You can use periodicity of the trig functions to take care of the missing points. If you know about quotient topology, you get an induced homeomorphism from $[0,2\pi]\times [0,2\pi]\big/\big((0,\phi)\sim (2\pi,\phi) \text{ and } (\theta,0)\sim (\theta,2\pi)\big)$ to the torus in $\Bbb R^3$.

With regard to my comment about the $z$-axis, my point was that the function 
$$f\colon\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R\,, \quad f(x,y,z) = \big(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-b\big)^2 + z^2$$
is only smooth away from $x^2+y^2=0$, i.e., the $z$-axis. To apply the regular value theorem, you have to start with a smooth function and then check that your value — in this case, $a^2$ — is a regular value. So I suggested deleting the $z$-axis and considering $f$ with domain $\Bbb R^3-\{x=y=0\}$; now $f$ is smooth. :)

Comment: So with the original approach, I am still not sure what to do after the parameterization.

Comment: My aim is to find a function f such that for f:$ℝ^3$ →ℝ so that when we  said $S=f^−1(c)$  which is a two-dimensional manifold. (n=3, m=1; 3-1 = 2) but I'm struggling to define what f is. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Kagami: I've edited to elaborate a bit on the first. To apply the regular value theorem, the $f$ is the one that appeared in the original post and that I gave you again above!

Comment: Thank you, Ted. After I have a think about it, I have realized that there are different ways of parameterizing the equation. The equation you wrote, it was actually in Caratesian form and it is the parametrized of the torus right? So if I make my f(x,y,z) = $\quad f(x,y,z) = \big(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-b\big)^2 + z^2 - a^2$ , then would f be now smooth in domain  $ℝ^3$ or am I completely off?

Comment: You didn't change anything but a constant. This function is *still* not differentiable when $x=y=0$. You could do a bunch of algebra and get rid of the square root. Something like $g(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2+b^2-a^2)^2 - 4b^2(x^2+y^2)=0$. (No guarantees!) But why bother? There are no points on your torus lying on the bad set $x=y=0$, so it's no problem.